# is Android not supporting USSD CALL?

Tags: android, telephony, ussd

I'm trying to make a USSD call on my app

I tried to do this :

```
Intent fastCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
String Num = "*100*200"+ Uri.encode("#");
fastCall.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Num));
startActivity(fastCall);
```

but I keep getting an error:

```
Connection problem or invalid MMI code
```

what can I do ? or should I just use `ACTION_DIAL`?

any idea ?

Comment: Are you testing it on real device?

Comment: YES, and still getting that error , i'm confused

Comment: Make sure your operator support that MMI code

Comment: I'm testing it on Galaxy S5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Android does not fully support USSD. Notice that there are no actual USSD APIs.  Your dialer may or may not send USSD codes.  Really its a technology that no longer makes sense in today's world where we have actual data connections.  A given code may work depending on device, dialer, SIP installation, carrier, etc.  Or it may not.  In any case there's no reliable way to get any answering data.

Comment: thanks for the info Gabe, so i guess i should just use ACTION_DIAL instead of directly using ACTION_CALL

Answer (score 1):

I think using ACTION_DIAL can not work well yet. ACTION_DIAL used to lunch system dialer app.